# How to exit from while loop with condition Scanner hasNext()

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

Found the solution below on Hyperskills.org (considered as correct solution) - can anybody explain how this code can work if while loop is endless? I mean (scanner.hasNext()) is always true.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     ArrayList<String> questList = new ArrayList<>();

     while (scanner.hasNext()) {
         String nextGuest = scanner.next();
         questList.add(nextGuest);
     }

     Collections.reverse(questList);

     questList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: "I mean (scanner.hasNext()) is always true." it is not always true. It just waits for data since `System.in` is still opened, meaning that new data is still *possible*. But if you close `System.in` (in windows you could do it with `Ctrl`+`Z` combination - assuming you are running it from console) it will see that new data can't come and will return `false` causing loop to exit.

Comment: Ctrl + Z doesn't work in InetlliJ......

Comment: But to avoid relying on user knowledge about how to close System.in (or to simply not close it since we may want to read from it later) we usually add explicit exit loop value like `stop` `exit` etc. to break from loop.

Comment: So you could rewrite that loop into something more like `boolean stopAsking = false; while(!stopAsking && scanner.hasNext()){String nextGuest = scanner.next(); if(nextGuest.equals("EXIT")){ stopAsking = true; } else { questList.add(nextGuest);} }`.

Comment: Actually hasNext() method is overloaded and there is one option with argument hasNext("EXIT") - and the loop whould break once EXIT us entered..the wierd thing is why Hyperskills consider the original solution as correct one

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to (A) negate result of `hasNext` like `while(!scanner.hasNext("EXIT")){..}` and (B) use `next()` method after loop to read that value from Scanner (assiming you may want to use it somewhere else in your application). Remember that any `hasABC` methods will not *consume* any value, it is `next`, `nextLine` or `nextTYPE` which let scanner move to next token.

Comment: I am suspecting that while testing Hyperskills is not using console/process input stream, but replace it with some steram containing finite amount of predefined data like file, for instance via `System.setIn(new FileInputStream("userData.txt"));`. Then such stream after seeing file ended will return EndOfFile signal which will let `hasNext` return `false`.

Comment: Yes, with reading from File hasNext() would work ideally.

Comment: @IljaVeselov Try using control-d to close a stream from the console under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the infinite loop based on some condition e.g. in the code given below, I have used `while(true){}` which is an infinite loop which will run until the user enters `quit` (case-insensitive).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> questList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {// Infinite loop
            String nextGuest = scanner.next();
            if (nextGuest.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                break;
            }
            questList.add(nextGuest);
        }

        Collections.reverse(questList);

        questList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
a1
b2
c3
quit
c3
b2
a1
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will keep going while the scanner has another token in its input. Inside the while loop, you are advancing the scanner with scanner.next(), so the scanner isn't stationary. So eventually scanner.hasNext() will be False.